# Capturar datos de un subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Estoy tratando de capturar la data que me regresa el subscribe en el success. Hasta ahora no he logrado hacerlo. Soy nuevo con typescript y no se que este haciendo mal o como podria capturar la data que se me regresa.

Nota: Estoy capturando datos que vienen desde un modulo bluetooth arduino hacia mi app en celular.

```
 deviceConnected() {
    // Subscribe to data receiving as soon as the delimiter is read
    this.bluetoothSerial.subscribe('\n').subscribe(success => {

      this.showError(success);

    }, error => {
      this.showError(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hola!, por que haces doble subscribe? Tienes algún error en la consola, en el ng serve? Por que pones `subscribe('\n')`? Generalmente los subscribe reciben una función de flecha.

Comment: Hola, la documentacion que estoy usando me pide que lo ponga asi. BluetoothSerial

Comment: puedes poner esa doc?

Comment: bluetoothSerial es un servicio de tu app, por lo tanto con llamar this.bluetoothSerial, no es suficiente, debes añadir la funcion que quieres ejecutar perteneciente al servicio bluetoothSerial es decir: this.bluetoothSerial.METODO_NECESARIO.subscribe( (success:any) => {}, (error:any) => {});

Answer (score 0):

[Según la documentación](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial#subscribe), para usar el método `subscribe` que ofrece esa librería tienes que pasarle 3 parámetros:

```
bluetoothSerial.subscribe(delimiter, success, failure);
```

siendo el último parámetro opcional.

Para tu caso concreto sería así:

```
deviceConnected() {
    // Subscribe to data receiving as soon as the delimiter is read
    this.bluetoothSerial.subscribe(
        '\n', // delimiter
        success => { // success
            // Acciones a realizar cuando todo haya ido ok
        }, error => { // failure
            // Acciones a realizar cuando haya un error
        }
    );
}
```

Espero que te sirva para continuar